# Closed Form for this Taylor Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion, closed-form

Does anybody know whether or not this sum has a closed form?
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!(2^n+1)}$$
I can't get WA to even understand it when I type it in.

For context, the reason I want to know is that I calculated it as the solution to the functional equation
$$f(x)+f(2x)=e^x$$

Comment: It's really close to $e^{x/2}$. I'm skeptical there's a nice closed form; Wolfram won't even evaluate the sum in closed form for $x = 1$.

Comment: If I haven't made a mistake (quite possible since I didn't use pen and paper), it's $$\exp(x/2) - \sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} (-1)^k \bigl(\exp (2^{-k}x) - 1\bigr).$$ Wouldn't call that a closed form, though.

Comment: Perhaps $f(2x)+f(4x)=(f(x)+f(2x))^2$ is obvious but useful.

Comment: @Somos Perhaps not useful, but certainly interesting. :D

Comment: @Somos Also, the link in your other answer to all of the algebraic identities isn't working. Do you mind giving me a working link? I would really like to visit that page.

Comment: Not a closed form, but amusingly $f(x)=e^{\frac x2}-e^{\frac x4}+e^{\frac x8}-e^{\frac{x}{16}}+...$

Comment: @DavidQuinn The alternating sum need +1/2 since $f(0)=1/2$.

Comment: @Nilknarf I have tried that link with three different browsers. I don't see the problem. Here is the URL: http://somos.crg4.com/ident04.gp or goto the site directly http://somos.crg4.com/index.html

Comment: @DavidQuinn Hm, that's interesting...

Comment: @Somos Darn, I can't get to either of those! :(